# Match strings with no more than one @ character in succession

Tags: regex

I need to make sure that specified character (`@`) repeats no more than one time in succession. It can occur multiple times, but only as a single `@` character, not `@@` or more. Capturing groups are unnecessary.

These strings should be matched:

```
foobar
@foobar
foo@bar
foo@bar@baz
```

These strings should not be matched:

```
@@foobar
foo@@bar
foo@bar@@baz
```

The engine supports lookaheads and lookbehinds.

I've tried do this with `(?<!@)@(?!@)` for exactly 1 repetition, but  `((?<!@)@(?!@)|)` or `(?<!@)@?(?!@)` obviously won't work as intended for 0 or 1 repetition.

How can this situation be handled?

Comment: What if a line doesn't have any @ chars? Should it match or not?

Comment: @S.Imp It should. This case is listed in *These strings should be matched*.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free consultation for creating a regex for you. What have you tried, how did it go wrong, and what did you do to try to resolve the problem?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It sounds like a fair regex question to me. The question is implied, but I can add a sentence with question mark if this is a problem. I'm not sure how to approach the described issue, not because I'm lazy to write a regexp.

Comment: So what research have you executed so far to increase your knowledge in this area? Adding a sentence with a question mark won't change the fact that no research effort is shown here.

Comment: Note that testing if the string contains `@@` with a simple string function is from far faster.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm intermediate at regexps and do my regexp gym in the morning, but this was lookaround-fu that I couldn't handle. Just ran out of ideas.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks, sure. This regexp was supposed to be used in utility with regexp engine and no other reasonable ways of negative matching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any lookahead support you can use this negated character class regex:

```
^[^@]*(?:@[^@]+)*$
```

Where `[^@]` matches anything that is not `@`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HBka56/7)

If you have lookahead support in your regex then use a simpler regex:

```
^(?!.*@@).*$
```

Where `(?!.*@@)` is negative regex to disallow `@@` anywhere in string.

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/HBka56/8)